Getting posts from Instagram via Python Requests
Trying to do some basic API request via Python Requests to Instagram to get posts from a public facing account. Few questions here since I couldn't find solid answers about this.

Does that base_url still work because I saw "?__a=1" was changed? I keep getting an HTML from my response.text so hence my json.loads breaks

Does using the access_token from Meta apps get the Json I need?


Basically, do I need to fix anything in my code for the basic request?
import requests
import json
import time
import pandas as pd

# Function to scrape Instagram data
def scrape_instagram_data(username, num_posts):
    param = dict()
    param['access_token'] = "{my token is here}"
    base_url = f"https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1"
    response = requests.get(base_url,params=param)
    print(response.text) # Checking response output, getting 200 from this
    data = json.loads(response.text) #Breaks JSONdecodeError due to HTML output, wanting a JSON output

I was hoping to get a JSON output from this code but I'm getting an HTML output

I don't see any reason why Instagram would return json with that request. Can you explain why you are expecting a json response? If you're using some documentation or tutorial for this API, can you link to that?

Instead of json.loads(response.text) why not just directly data = response.json()?

That's not an API endpoint. You're going to have to either scrape the HTML you're getting now or use the actual API.

Yup I figured that out now. I've gone down the API route but running into issues getting post information from a public account (in my test case I've been using Food network, foodnetwork,) So I've been trying to hit the "https://graph.instagram.com/v19.0/foodnetwork". So my question is can I even query a public account? It works on the test user I've assigned the access token to but no other public accounts using the following url: "https://graph.instagram.com/v19.0/me".
